# Asciidoctor Font

Tags: yaml, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

How do I add the default font of Asciidoctor HTML to Asciidoctor pdf? Can I use the Webfont example: "@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic%7CNoto+Serif:400,400italic,700,700italic%7CDroid+Sans+Mono:400,700); " to my attributes file for the pdf format?

Answer (score 1):

The webfont example you gave works for HTML output, when the styling is done with CSS. For Asciidoctor-pdf, the styling is not done with CSS but through a YML file, [here is the default Asciidoctor-pdf theme](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/data/themes/default-theme.yml).

If you want the Asciidoctor HTML style in PDF you will need to check the [Asciidoctor default CSS](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/asciidoctor/asciidoctor@2.0/data/stylesheets/asciidoctor-default.css) and try to recreate it for Asciidoctor-pdf. If you are only interested in the font you will probably need the [Open Sans font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans), I did not find a way to include a web font so you will have to download it and create your custom theme.

The default font in Asciidoctor-pdf is Noto Serif, a simple way to change it to Open Sans would be to create a `custom-theme.yml` file like this:

```
extends: default
font:
  catalog:
    merge: true
    Open Sans:
      normal: OpenSans-Regular.ttf
      bold: OpenSans-Bold.ttf
      italic: OpenSans-Italic.ttf
      bold_italic: OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
base:
  font_family: Open Sans
```

More information about theming in the [Asciidoctor PDF Theming Guide](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/docs/theming-guide.adoc)
Organize your files like this:

```
yourFile.adoc
resources/themes/custom-theme.yml
resources/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
resources/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
resources/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf
resources/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
```

and set your custom theme as an attribute when calling `asciidoctor-pdf` like this:

```
asciidoctor-pdf -a pdf-theme=resources/themes/custom-theme.yml -a pdf-fontsdir="resources/fonts;GEM_FONTS_DIR" yourFile.adoc
```